# How to loop through nested Json object?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

This my `JSON` data which I am getting:

```
{
  "trains": [
    {
      "id": "12142",
      "code": "12125",
      "name": "D-Some",
      "codeandname": "Express1OMin_1"
    },
    {
      "id": "12189",
      "code": "1217887",
      "name": "Express2One",
      "codeandname": "Express2OneKL_Min"
    },
    {
      "id": "1225896",
      "code": "23599",
      "name": "Express235KYTgg",
      "codeandname": "ExpressTh89554"
    },
}
```

I want to display `codeandname` in list format in my `Ionic` application.
This is what I tried:

```
<ion-item>
        <ion-label color="primary" floating>Enter Train No./Name</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="TrainName" (input)="searching($event)" clearInput></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let stations of stationlist" (click)="itemSelected(stations)">{{stations}}</ion-item>
      </ion-list>
```

My `TS` file:

```
searching(ev) 
  {
    var val = ev.target.value;
    this.share.FetchStations(val).subscribe(data => 
      {
      // this.stationlist=data.trains.codeandname;
      console.log(data.trains.length);
      for (var j=0; j < data.trains.length; j++) 
      {
        this.stationlist=data.trains[j].codeandname;
        console.log(this.stationlist);
      }     
      }
    )
  }
```

But this do not worked. How do I achieve this? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: checking your object could take less time than asking this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looping Object you can not loop object Try this way

```
<ion-item>
            <ion-label color="primary" floating>Enter Train No./Name</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="TrainName" (input)="searching($event)" clearInput></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-list>
            <ion-item *ngFor="let stations of stationlist.trains" (click)="itemSelected(stations)">{{stations.codeandname}}</ion-item>
          </ion-list>
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vbfjby

Comment: I am new to this. Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

this a simple example for listing data related to nested arrays

array of objects contains nested array

```
  public models :any[] = [
    {
      name : 'name 01',
      items: [1,2,3,4,6]
    },
    {
      name : 'name 02',
      items: [55,6,20,4]
    },
    {
      name : 'name 03',
      items: [9,8,9,2,47]
    },
  ]
```

template

```
<div *ngFor="let model of models">
  <div>{{model.name}}</div>
  <div *ngFor="let item of model.items">
    {{item}}
  </div>
</div>
```

> Second loop we iterator throw the object from current iteration `model.items`

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p9csid)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. That really helped!!

Answer (score 1):

Look at the structure of the **`JSON`**, it is an **`Object`** which has **`array`** in it. By definition you can use **`ngFor`** over an array.

So you should change your ngFor to use over an array **`trains`** which resides inside the object **`stationlist`**,

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let stations of stationlist.trains" (click)="itemSelected(stations)">{{stations}}</ion-item>
```

**[`DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rymb2b?file=src/app/app.component.html)**